# Finding where a complex series converges absolutely, uniformly.

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I need to figure out where the series converges absolutely and uniformly.  I know that once I have absolute convergence on a region, then I know I also have uniform convergence on that region, so I really only need to check one thing.

$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{z-3})^k$

Also, what complex function does this series represent?

What I did was try to use the n-th root test to find the radius of convergence.  Does that sound like the right thing to do so far?

Comment: If you want to know if it converges absolutely, check $\sum_{k=0}^\infty|a_n|$ converges.  For your case, we'd want $|\frac1{z-3}|\le1$ (geometric series)

Comment: as Simple said, it is the same as $\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k$ with $x = 1/(z-3)$. this power series clearly diverges on $|x| \ge 1$, so all you have to do is looking at $|x| < 1$. and be careful : it doesn't converge uniformly on $|x| < 1$ but on $|x| \le 1-\epsilon$ for any fixed $\epsilon > 0$ (which is not the same)

Comment: It's certainly not true in general that an absolutely convergent series converges uniformly!